# aks can't create a kubernetes replica set

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

When trying to create a kubernetes replica set from a yaml file, then I always get this error on AKS:

> kubectl create -f kubia-replicaset.yaml error: unable to recognize
>   "kubia-replicaset.yaml": no matches for apps/, Kind=ReplicaSet

I tried it with several different files and also the samples from the K8s documentation, but all result in this failure. Creating Pods and RCs works

below is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: kubia
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubia
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubia
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubia
        image: luksa/kubia
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are <strike>supposed</strike> advised to use [deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) now:

> A Deployment controller provides declarative updates for Pods and
>   ReplicaSets.
>
> You describe a desired state in a Deployment object, and the
>   Deployment controller changes the actual state to the desired state at
>   a controlled rate. You can define Deployments to create new
>   ReplicaSets, or to remove existing Deployments and adopt all their
>   resources with new Deployments.

And this piece:

> Kubectl rolling update updates Pods and ReplicationControllers in a
>   similar fashion. But Deployments are recommended, since they are
>   declarative, server side, and have additional features, such as
>   rolling back to any previous revision even after the rolling update is
>   done.

Also, take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#example)

Comment: Still why is it not possible to create a replica set on its own? I know deployments are the way to go, but I just want to be able to work with the samples from my Kubernetes book

Comment: look at the example i linked, its using `apps/v1`

Comment: yes, I tried also with exactly this sample and with this API version. All resulted in the same error :/ otherwise I wouldn't have asked here

Comment: solved it, I needed to change the API to  extensions/v1beta1

Answer (score 9):

Change apps/v1beta2 to apps/v1 works for me.